# Is there a way in vim to make :W to do the same thing as :w?

Tags: vim

The same goes for :q and :Q. I almost always don't let up on shift quick enough and seeing that :Q and :W aren't used anyway I thought it would be nice to just have them do the same as their lower-case counterparts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hack is via a `:cmap` or `:cabb`, but these have side effects (i.e. other instances will be inadvertently converted, too).

The [cmdalias plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) does this better.

But I think for your use case it's best to define your own uppercase command-variants. The main challenge is to support all the options that the original one has:

```
command! -bang -range=% -complete=file -nargs=* W <line1>,<line2>write<bang> <args>
command! -bang Q quit<bang>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also, how would I unmap a command?  Id like to do the same thing for :x and :X, because I don't ever use encryption.

Comment: also, is there a difference between what you wrote and:  

command! Q q
command! W w

Comment: @dwcanillas: :X is special; normally Vim commands are lowercase. You would have to use cmdalias for that one.

Comment: @dwcanillas: The simple `command! W w` wouldn't pass on ranges or filenames. Commands are not simply substituted like mappings!

Comment: Ingo: why is defining uppercase command-variants better than using the cmdalias plugin? I'm in the same situation as OP: constantly finding myself having typed :W instead of :w.

Comment: @dgrogan: The `:W` command is first-class; you can auto-complete it, use it in mappings, record it, put it in history or in a Vimscript, and so on. The cmdalias works by manipulating the command-line as you type it, and there are some odd behaviors sometimes (though you usually don't notice). But: If you already use cmdalias, just go ahead and define a `:W` alias with it, too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can remap them in your .vimrc like so:

```
cabb W w
cabb Q q
```

or

```
cmap W w
cmap Q q
```

The downside is that it "W" will expand to "w" with both cases (`cmap` displays the change, `cabb` does not).

It's generally quite easy to remap keys to suit your needs in Vim. Try looking at the following tutorial: [Mapping keys in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)

**edit:**
As @IngoKarkat points out, this is a hackish solution. I'm leaving it here because it's fast and easy. However, the downside is clear; it interferes with other uses.

Comment: This has bad side effects; e.g. how do you search for capitalized "Willy" or "Queen" then?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm pretty new to vimrc so I had a hard time understanding the key mappings when I looked at the wiki and in the help.  I'm not actually sure I found the page you linked to though, that page seems to do a good job explaining everything. Thanks again!

Comment: This is indeed a hackish solution. @IngoKarkat's solution is better, I suggest you accept his instead.

Comment: don't do it - it prevents entering capital W and Q in command line

Answer (score 3):

noremap works for me with no known side effects

```
noremap :W :w
```

Comment: The side effect of your approach is that there is now a delay after typing `:`, before command-line mode becomes active. It's minimal, but I find this lack of immediate feedback irritating.

Comment: yeah, I guess it does cause a delay if I only type `:` but I almost never type `:` and then wait for command mode to become active before typing my command so it hasn't bothered me.

Comment: @IngoKarkat `nnoremap :W :w<cr> , it will remove the lag
`

Answer (score 3):

You can define `W` and `Q` by adding the following entries to your `.vimrc`:

```
command! W write
command! Q quit
```

Comment: This is a really clean solution

Answer (score 2):

### Assuming you're looking for a quicker way to do `:wq`

Really this is a combo of <kbd>ESC</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd> (which itself is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>) then <kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>q</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Five keystrokes, six if you count <kbd>:</kbd> as two.

Instead, try <kbd>ESC</kbd> then (holding) <kbd>Shift</kbd> press <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> again (no <kbd>:</kbd> at all).  It will save and quit the file immediately.  One less keystroke (or two, depending upon how you count it) plus much harder to mess up.

Comment: While this is not per se an answer to the question, it is a solution to the underlying problem. A big +1.  However, 'shift+z+z' is not a shortcut for `:wq` but for `:x`. The difference is explained here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5726/7979

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem — "I almost always don't let up on shift quick enough". Swap the meaning of the colon and semicolon. Then no shift is needed, as you will use `;w` and `;q`.

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
vnoremap ; :
vnoremap : ;
```