# Remapping :Wq to :wq in vim

Tags: vim, customization

A lot of times, when I want to save a file in vim and immediately exit thereafter, I accidentally type :Wq instead of :wq.

Vim naturally gives me this error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: Wq
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to remap :Wq to :wq?

Comment: Just use `:x`? Or follow the answers to also map `:X` ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a simple vim command that is basically an alias for `wq`. Place the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
command! Wq wq
```

For more help see:

```
:h :command
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `ZZ` which is the same as `:wq<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

Though abbreviations suggest themselves for this (`:cnoreabbrev Wk wk`), their main disadvantage is that they are also applied in other places, such as when using `Wk` in a search pattern.

With the [cmdalias plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746), you can define an alias:

```
:Alias Wk wk
```

<sup>PS: There is no `:wk` command, did you mean `:wn[ext]`? For a simple `:w`, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590165/is-there-a-way-in-vim-to-make-w-to-do-the-same-thing-as-w)</sup>

Comment: @PeterRincker You should post that as an answer.  It's much more elegant than having a plugin to accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah, for the argument-less `:wq`, I would probably also use a command, but I like the plugin for more advanced uses (which almost inevitably come up sooner or later).

Comment: Your answer is good and it worked for me, but the Peter's one suits better my needs. I just want a quick way to do the mapping, and I have many computer with Vim installed. It's simpler to use a "pluginless" solution.